# Support C# Class Libraries to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, c#-4.0

I am new to Wordpress. Planning to develop a new website by using WP.

My question is, I have C# Class Library already. Is it **possible / any way** to use this C# DLL's as server side to Wordpress ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.

Comment: @stink  :Thanks for ur reply.